# VBA find works only once after open

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which involves searching for a date in a dynamic range.

If I close and re-open the workbook, it works fine. However, if I try to run the exact same macro a second, third or fourth time, the section where I search for "z" returns `Nothing` for "z", even though the search variable ("x") is defined as the correct date, a corresponding date exists in the range, and the range is being properly defined.

This question was asked and answered previously, and on that occasion, the problem was that the OP had not included a "LookIn". I, however, have.

It fails on the line `set z = .Find (x, Lookin:= xlValues)` - this returns `Nothing`.

```
Sub Calculate_Nights_days()
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim crng As Range
    Dim sValue As Date
    Dim sRng As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim v As Integer
    Dim WsT As Worksheet
    Dim lastrowTotals As Long
    Dim WsTDateRange As Range

    Set WsT = Worksheets("Totals")

    'Nights
    lastrowTotals = WsT.Cells(WsT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastrowTotals > 1 Then
        WsT.Range("A2:A" & lastrowTotals).ClearContents
        WsT.Range("B2:B" & lastrowTotals).ClearContents
        WsT.Range("C2:C" & lastrowTotals).ClearContents
    Else
    End If

    Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each Ws In Workbooks("Nights and Days").Worksheets
        If Ws.Name <> "Totals" Then
            Ws.Activate

            lastrow = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set crng = Ws.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)

            EndDate = Application.Max(crng)
            StartDate = Application.Min(crng)

            For x = StartDate To EndDate
                v = 0

                For Each y In crng
                    If y = x And y.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Night" Then
                        v = v + 1
                    End If
                Next y

                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(WsT.Range("A:A")) = 0 Then
                    WsT.Range("A2").Value = x
                    WsT.Range("B2").Value = v
                Else
                    lastrowTotals = WsT.Cells(WsT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    WsT.Range("A" & lastrowTotals).Offset(1, 0).Value = x
                    WsT.Range("A" & lastrowTotals).Offset(1, 1).Value = v
                End If
            Next x
        Else
        End If        
    Next


    'Days
    lastrowTotals = WsT.Cells(WsT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each Ws In Workbooks("Nights and Days").Worksheets
        If Ws.Name <> "Totals" Then
            Ws.Activate

            lastrow = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set crng = Ws.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)

            EndDate = Application.Max(crng)
            StartDate = Application.Min(crng)

            For x = StartDate To EndDate
                v = 0

                For Each y In crng
                    If y = x And y.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Day" Then
                        v = v + 1
                    End If
                Next y

                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(WsT.Range("A:A")) = 0 Then
                    WsT.Range("A2").Value = x
                    WsT.Range("C2").Value = v
                Else
                    lastrowTotals = WsT.Cells(WsT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    Set WsTDateRange = WsT.Range("A2:A" & lastrowTotals)

                    With WsTDateRange
                        Set z = .Find(x, LookIn:=xlValues)
                        If Not z Is Nothing Then
                            firstAddress = z.Address
                            Do
                                z.Offset(0, 2).Value = v
                                Set z = .FindNext(z)
                                If z Is Nothing Then
                                    GoTo DoneFinding
                                End If
                            Loop While z Is Nothing And z.Address <> firstAddress
                        End If
 DoneFinding:
                    End With
                End If
            Next x
        Else
        End If
    Next

    WsT.Activate

    Range("A2:A" & lastrowTotals).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    Range("B2:B" & lastrowTotals).NumberFormat = "General"
    Range("C2:C" & lastrowTotals).NumberFormat = "General"

    WsT.Range("A2:C50000").CurrentRegion.Sort WsT.Range("A2"), xlAscending

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Also, the penultimate line: 

    WsT.Range("A2:C50000").CurrentRegion.Sort WsT.Range("A2"), xlAscending

does not sort properly - this is supposed to sort columns A to C from the second row down.  Instead, it filters all values including the top row, so that the text headings at the top of each of these columns go beneath the date-ordered values.

Comment: Perhaps you should add `Dim z as Range` and try again? It may work out, who knows?

Comment: And for the penultimate line, try this:             `WsT.Range("A2:C50000").CurrentRegion.Sort WsT.Range("A2:C2"), xlAscending`

Comment: @Vityata using Header := xlYes has resolved the second problem.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should always use `Option Explicit` in order to make sure that all of your variables are declared correctly and typing mistakes won't cause errors at runtime.

As a second point - try to format a bit your code, too many empty lines and bad indention is a bit not understandable. Take a look at the code below, and if you want, copy it to your question.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Calculate_Nights_days()

    Dim Ws                      As Worksheet
    Dim starting_ws             As Worksheet
    Dim StartDate               As Date
    Dim EndDate                 As Date
    Dim crng                    As Range
    Dim sValue                  As Date
    Dim sRng                    As Range
    Dim lastrow                 As Long
    Dim v                       As Long
    Dim WsT                     As Worksheet
    Dim lastrowTotals           As Long
    Dim WsTDateRange            As Range
    Dim x                       As Long
    Dim y                       As Range
    Dim z                       As Range
    Dim firstAddress            As String

    Set WsT = Worksheets("Totals")
    lastrowTotals = WsT.Cells(WsT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If lastrowTotals > 1 Then

        WsT.Range("A2:A" & lastrowTotals).ClearContents
        WsT.Range("B2:B" & lastrowTotals).ClearContents
        WsT.Range("C2:C" & lastrowTotals).ClearContents

    End If

    Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each Ws In Workbooks("Nights and Days").Worksheets
        If Ws.Name <> "Totals" Then
            Ws.Activate
            lastrow = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set crng = Ws.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)

            EndDate = Application.Max(crng)
            StartDate = Application.Min(crng)

            For x = StartDate To EndDate
                v = 0
                For Each y In crng
                    If y = x And y.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Night" Then
                        v = v + 1
                    End If
                Next y

                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(WsT.Range("A:A")) = 0 Then
                    WsT.Range("A2").Value = x
                    WsT.Range("B2").Value = v
                Else


                    lastrowTotals = WsT.Cells(WsT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    WsT.Range("A" & lastrowTotals).Offset(1, 0).Value = x
                    WsT.Range("A" & lastrowTotals).Offset(1, 1).Value = v
                End If
            Next x
        End If
    Next


    lastrowTotals = WsT.Cells(WsT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each Ws In Workbooks("Nights and Days").Worksheets
        If Ws.Name <> "Totals" Then
            Ws.Activate
            lastrow = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set crng = Ws.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
            EndDate = Application.Max(crng)
            StartDate = Application.Min(crng)

            For x = StartDate To EndDate
                v = 0
                For Each y In crng
                    If y = x And y.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Day" Then
                        v = v + 1
                    End If
                Next y

                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(WsT.Range("A:A")) = 0 Then
                    WsT.Range("A2").Value = x
                    WsT.Range("C2").Value = v
                Else
                    lastrowTotals = WsT.Cells(WsT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    Set WsTDateRange = WsT.Range("A2:A" & lastrowTotals)

                    With WsTDateRange

                        Set z = .Find(x, LookIn:=xlValues)
                        If Not z Is Nothing Then
                            firstAddress = z.Address
                            Do
                                z.Offset(0, 2).Value = v
                                Set z = .FindNext(z)
                                If z Is Nothing Then
                                    GoTo DoneFinding
                                End If
                            Loop While z Is Nothing And z.Address <> firstAddress
                        End If
DoneFinding:
                    End With
                End If
            Next x
        End If
    Next

    WsT.Activate
    Range("A2:A" & lastrowTotals).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    Range("B2:B" & lastrowTotals).NumberFormat = "General"
    Range("C2:C" & lastrowTotals).NumberFormat = "General"
    WsT.Range("A2:C50000").CurrentRegion.Sort WsT.Range("A2:C2"), xlAscending

End Sub
```

I have changed the following:
 - WsT.Range("A2:C50000").CurrentRegion.Sort WsT.Range("A2:C2"), xlAscending
 - Integer to long
 - removed the useless `Else`
 - defined the undefined `z`,`x`,`y` and `firstAddress`

Change also the way you look the find:
`set z = .Find (x, Lookin:= xlPart)`
`xlPart` may give different results than `xlWhole`.

It may work. Good luck!